What's the feedback network in this shunt-shunt positive feedback?
This is the circuit from solutions from problem 2 from Tutorial 1 on Integrated Radio Frequency Circuits , \$I_1, I_2\$ are current source, which can be removed (\$\textbf{open circuit}\$) in small signal analysis.

At node X,
$$
\frac{V_{in} - V_X} {R_S} = \frac{V_X} {r_{o2}} + V_{out} g_{m2}
$$
At node \$V_{out}\$,
$$
V_X g_{m1} + \frac{V_{out}} {r_{o1}} =0
$$
$$
\Rightarrow
\frac{V_{out}} {V_{in}}
=
\frac{\mbox{$\Large \frac{g_{m1}} {R_S}$} (R_S \parallel r_{o2})}
{g_{m1} g_{m2} (R_S \parallel r_{o2}) - 1/r_{o1}}
$$
$$
\Rightarrow
\frac{V_{out}} {V_{in}}
=
\frac{-\mbox{$\Large\frac{g_{m1}} {R_S}$} (R_S \parallel r_{o2}) r_{o1}}
{1 - g_{m1} g_{m2} (R_S \parallel r_{o2}) r_{o1}}
$$
In the open loop using two port analysis, we can replace this voltage source with Norton equivalent.

$$
V_{in}= I_{in} R_S
$$
$$
I_{in} = \frac{V_X} {R_S} +  \frac{V_X} {r_{o2}} + V_{out} g_{m2}
$$
$$
\frac{V_{out}} {r_{o1}} = 0
$$
However, it looks like it's incorrect.
Where am I wrong?

@Burglups I'm trying to find open loop rather than loop gain.

How is $M_1$ feeding anything back? That is the main (feed-forward) transistor.

@a360pilot What's the feedback network if $M_1$ is not feeding anything back? Can you analyse it with two port network?

If I1 and I2 are two constant current sources, they are shorted together with the other constant source . The equivalent circuit is a differences or increments based circuit.

This looks like a +ve FB latch with no gain.  Pls cite source. Vo = RdsOn(M2)*I1

otherwise missing assumptions  if your source or otherwise fake design

@D.A.S. Please see my updates on source

You seem to be creating content based on others because there are subtle differences such as the wrong PFET symbol.  If I wanted to know, I would ask site mgr Ted.Johansson@liu.se to get in touch with author and suggest there is a conceptual error using a positive feedback circuit in that pdf file that cannot amplify signals unless it is intended to be a noise source.  Otherwise it is just noise (lol) Are you expecting renumberation for your content posted here?

@D.A.S. I didn't understand why you say my pmos symbol is wrong.

The short-hand textbook standard does not use the arrow AND the Not circle.  Use the IEC stds https://i.sstatic.net/TMZqYrzJ.png

I meant IPC STDs. Don’t invent your own


Open-loop gain Aol: When we neglect the input impedances of the transistors, the open-loop gain of the amplifier stage M1 (M2 disconnected) is
Aol=-gm1*ro1. (ro1: output resistance of M1)

Loop gain Alg: Due to the neglected input impedance we can open the loop without any  loading errors. Therefore, the loop gain is simply
Alg=-gm1*ro1[- gm2 * (Rs||ro2)]

Closed-loop gain Acl: Due to the classic feedback expression, we have Acl==Aol/(1-Alg)



If you can't neglect  input impedances of the transistors, what will be the $A_{ol}$

@ kile - when the input impedances at the gate must not be neglected, the gain of the main amplifier M1 (open-llop gain)  is determined by ro1||rin2.

What is $r_{in2}$?Can you give me more details? Can you draw a schematic?

@ kile - I do not understand the background of your question. In my comment, I have mentioned the input impedance at the gate - and in the corresponding expression I wrote "rin2".

Can you write it in the form of $r_o$ and $g_m$?
